# need a push in the right direction with js/php gallery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, gallery

I'm trying to create an image gallery. Most of it is working as intended, however, the thing I want to change on this gallery is so that when I click on the next picture or previous picture, I want the thumbnails to show the next 8 pictures. At the moment it's showing the next picture

PHP code:

```
<?php
$pics = glob("img/2016/*/*.{JPG,PNG,GIF,jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
if(count($pics)) {
    rsort($pics);
    foreach($pics as $pictures) {
        echo "<a href='$pictures' target='_blank'><img class='Gallery' src='$pictures'></a>";
    }
    echo '<a class="button-floating lbutton" onclick="plusDivs(-1);plusThumbs(-1)"><div class="gall_nav">&#10094;</div></a>';
    echo '<a class="button-floating rbutton" onclick="plusDivs(1);plusThumbs(1)"><div class="gall_nav">&#10095;</div></a>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="thumbs_container">';
    foreach(array_slice($pics, 1) as $thumbs)
        if ($thumb++ < 8){
            echo "<a href='$thumbs' target='_blank'><img class='thumbs' src='$thumbs'></a>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, no images to display!";
    }
    ?>
```

The code is showing 1 thumbnail which updates correctly, but I want 8 thumbnails at least..

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("Gallery");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length} ;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 

var thumbIndex = slideIndex +1;
showThumbs(thumbIndex);

function plusThumbs(t){
showThumbs(thumbIndex += t);
}

function showThumbs(t){
    var g;
    var getThumb = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbs");
    if (t > getThumb.length) {thumbIndex = 1}
    if (t < 1) {thumbIndex = getThumb.length};
    for (g = 0; g < getThumb.length; g++){
        getThumb[g].style.display = "none";
    }
getThumb[thumbIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}
}
```

Any ideas on how I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope, I understood your idea and what you want to do. Anyway here is my advises. At first I would like to say, that building `html` tags using `php` is not even a good idea. It's always a better way to separate code, instead of making some kind of mix. So, I'll advice you to use your `php` script only to find all images and send an array of src to client side (in `JSON` format). When you get an array of src, you could make a gallery only using `javascript` or `jQuery`. With jQuery you could make a simple `GET` Ajax Request, in order to get an array of img's src. Then you could init your gallery.

The gallery you can make in this way:
[image]

So you have an id an change it by clicking `prev` or `next` buttons. After clicking you regenerate the current image and thumbs container.

Here is the working example (`jQuery`):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test App</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="galery">
  <div class="image_wrapper">
   <button class="prev">Prev</button>
   <img src="" alt="curr_image" class="curr_image" />
   <button class="next">Next</button>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbs_wrapper"></div>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   var fakeSrc = 
   ['src1', 'src2', 'src3', 'src4', 'src5', 'src6','src7', 'src8', 'src9', 'src10', 'src11'];

   var cId = 0;

   var thumbs_wrapper = $('.thumbs_wrapper');
   var curr_image = $('.curr_image');
   var prev = $('.prev');
   var next = $('.next');
   var updateThumbs = function() {
    var max = ( (cId + 9) > fakeSrc.length) ? fakeSrc.length : cId + 9;
    thumbs_wrapper.html('');

    for (var i = cId+1; i < max; ++i) {
     var img = document.createElement('img');
     img.className = 'thumb_image';
     var src = fakeSrc[i];
     img.alt = src;
     img.src = src;

     thumbs_wrapper.append(img);
    }
   }

   var setCurrImg = function() {
    curr_image.src = fakeSrc[cId];
    curr_image.prop('src', fakeSrc[cId]);
    curr_image.prop('alt', fakeSrc[cId]);
   }

   var updateGalery = function() {
    setCurrImg();
    updateThumbs();
   }

   prev.click(function() {
    --cId;
    if (cId < 0) cId = 0;
    updateGalery();
   });

   next.click(function() {
    ++cId;
    if (cId > fakeSrc.length - 1) cId = fakeSrc.length - 1;
    updateGalery();
   });

   updateGalery();
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope, that I've helped you to find the solution.

Comment: wow! thanks for this, the only problem is i dont really get what all that code does but i guess ill figure it out eventually :) Anyways, thanks again for the effort, ill try to mess around with it to se what everything does and so on :)

Comment: No problem! I'm ready to help you, when you will have any questions. :)

Comment: No worries m8 but thanks alot :) i just dont wanna use anything someone else wrote without understanding it :) guess im gonna take some online crash course on jquery... been dragging it out too long now :P